Diverging floating point calculation
I remember from computer science classes an example where the same floating-point calculation would diverge to infinity. From memory, it was something like this:
import time

def computation(f):

    f /= 7
    f += 1
    f *= 7
    f -= 7

    return f

f = 10
while True:
    f = computation(f)
    print(f)

But now I cannot reproduce it , and I cannot find it with an online search either. How can I find an example that illustrates the issues of cumulative rounding error in floating point calculations?

This is what you might be looking for.
```python
import time

def computation(f):
    f /= 7
    f += 1
    f *= 7
    f -= 7
    return f

f = 1e16
while True:
    f = computation(f)
    print(f)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Why this happens:
In floating-point arithmetic:
$f/7$ and $f*7$ precision loss means these may not perfectly cancel each other.
Performing $f /= 7$, means that the floating-point representation can store results slightly off from expected. This is more noticeable in very large or small numbers.
This is amplified in iterative computations. It won’t immediately result in a divergence to infinity, but the error can grow significantly over many iterations.
Explanation:

Floating-point division: Dividing by 7 results in a decimal approximation and so might introduce small inaccuracies, especially for very large numbers like $10^{16}$.
Reaccumulation of errors: Each iteration accumulates small inaccuracies. These will eventually cause noticeable deviations.
Precision loss with large numbers: starting with large values like $f = 10^{16}$, the floating-point representation cannot store the exact result of each division/multiplication, and so drifting occurs.

A good resource for exploring floating-point issues in detail is the online:

What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic

Also, check the IEEE 754 Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic

Thank you! I ran the code with 40 digits of precision and do not find a divergence nor a discrepancy.

You say “drifting occurs”. Does it really?

Python uses double-precision floating-point numbers (based on the IEEE 754 standard) so, rather than use the above simplistic example, try (part)
def computation(f):
large_value = 1e+16
small_value = 1e-10
f += small_value
f -= large_value  # Subtract a large value
f += large_value  # Add back the large value
return f
f = 1.
There are plenty of examples of floating-point errors, which is why it is still taught.  Being aware of the pitfalls helps look for ways to prevent errors.

Pick x. Let u be the value of the lowest bit of x. Then pick y such that y <= x <= y + 7u and y is an exact multiple of 7u.
We have y/7 <= x/7 <= y/7 + u, with y/7 and (y + 7u) / 7 calculated exactly. Adding 1 is an exact operation for most x, then multiplying by 7 is exact and so is subtracting 7. The new result is again between y and y+7u and that stays so forever. So the result may loop between a few values but won’t escape.
You need to handle small x, x just below a power of two, and very large x separately but I think you will get the same result. I wouldn’t be surprised if you get convergence quite quickly.
